# Webdriver with java for ASP.Net application

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, selenium, webdriver

i'm a new one here. For the few weeks i will be responsible in my new company for introduction of UI test automation for ASP.NET application. I've heard that i should prepare test scrips in the same language in which i have coded my applicaion, is it true? I got hope that it's not because i really will want to do this with webdriver and java not c#. My question is can i do this using java? It will be ok or maybe i must coding my test scripts in c#?

Will be very gratefull for help

Best regards
Michael

Comment: If it is only UI testing, the underlying language should not matter as you will be testing web pages. You might want to look at the tools/standards available to you at your new company as well

Comment: Hi, thank You very much for help. They develop apps in .Net and c# in visual studio and currently there is no test automation but i will want to use webdriver with java in inteli idea, so in Your opinion i can handle this in this way and there should not be any problems?

Answer (score 0):

The language or environment you use to create these unit tests shouldn't matter. However I've read your previous comments about your work using .Net, c# and visual studio, so i think it would be best for you to make use of their languages and programming environments. It's not a difficult transition from java to c# anyways (especially in the situation where you're only creating unit tests).

Comment: There will GUI tests not unit. I really care to make it with idea and java because i have never done itusing java but i want to learn it. Most tests are coded in java so i want to learn it and this is the reason why i want code test scripts in java for this all .net apps. As You said it does not matter so if my boss will pay for IDEA i will be very happy :D thx for help.